# Saml Implementation on diverse backend technologies

Tags: node.js, spring, saml, esb, saml-2.0

I need to implement SAML in Angular applications having variety of  backend technologies as java, node, an esb and a couple more. There are too many applications and can not rewrite backends, so what is the good stragedy / architecture to implement SAML ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In heterogeneous scenarios, I would personally use a multi-layered approach, enabling SAML at web-server level.

For instance, you can setup an **Apache** instance to use **Shibboleth** as access control module. Apache will indeed process all the HTTP/HTTPS requests, and Shibboleth will handle the SAML requests according to your configuration and your access rules.
However, take into account that you have to probably configure as well a **Gateway Interface** (i.e. WSGI for Python-based solutions) or a **proxy module** (`mod_proxxy`) in order to run your web applications against Apache.